# How to get the public ip of current ec2 instance in python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

How to obtain the public ip address of the current EC2 instance  in python ?

Comment: [This page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html) explains how to retrieve the IP address of your instance using an HTTP GET.

Answer (score 8):

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlopen("http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4").read()
```

Comment: Your answer is fairly brief, perhaps you could explain how this works. Is this amazon ec2 specific or something?

Comment: @CrazyCastaL Look here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html

Comment: The ``local-ipv4`` metadata will contain the private IP address of the instance which is useful only from within the AWS network.  The public IP address would be available as ``public-ipv4``.

Answer (score 4):

If you are already using `boto` you can also use the `boto.utils.get_instance_metadata` function.  This makes the call to the metadata server, gathers all of the metadata and returns it as a Python dictionary.  It also handles retries.

Answer (score 3):

```
import requests
ip = requests.get("http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4").content
```

Answer (score 2):

The following method will return the Public IP or Elastic IP address of your EC2 instance (Note: if an EIP address is associated with your EC2 instance, then the public IP address is actually released).

This is particularly useful for Django projects as you can append the IP address to ALLOWED_HOSTS in your settings.py script.

- Install PyCurl

  ```
  pip install pycurl
  ```
- Python 3

  ```
  import pycurl
  from io import BytesIO

  # Determine Public IP address of EC2 instance
  buffer = BytesIO()
  c = pycurl.Curl()
  c.setopt(c.URL, 'checkip.amazonaws.com')
  c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, buffer)
  c.perform()
  c.close()
  body = buffer.getvalue()
  # Body is a byte string, encoded. Decode it first.
  print (body.decode('iso-8859-1').strip())
  ```
- Python 2

  ```
  import pycurl
  from StringIO import StringIO

  buffer = StringIO()
  c = pycurl.Curl()
  c.setopt(c.URL, 'checkip.amazonaws.com')
  c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, buffer)
  c.perform()
  c.close()

  body = buffer.getvalue()
  # Body is a string in some encoding.
  # In Python 2, we can print it without knowing what the encoding is.
  print (body)
  ```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
def console(cmd):
    p = Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdout=PIPE)
    out,err = p.communicate()
    dir_list = out.split('\n')
    return (dir_list)
ip = console("http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4")
print ip
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is old but we can easily use `requests` library to get public ip as per below example

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://checkip.amazonaws.com/')
print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is a simple Python method to get the current Public IP address of an AWS ubuntu machine:**

**Code:**

```
def get_current_public_ip():
   url = "http://checkip.amazonaws.com"
   try:
       response = requests.get(url)
       if response.status_code == 200:
           ip_address = response.text.strip()
           return ip_address
       else:
           return None
   except requests.RequestException:
       return None
```